# One large SVG or many small SVG containers

Tags: svg, d3.js

I am appending 30-50 SVG shapes and paths to a map. The position of these shapes and paths will change based on map zoom. I have identified two ways of adding these shapes to the map:

1. Create a small SVG container for each individual shape / path. Position the shapes at a set point within the container. Position the containers relative to the window using CSS. Reposition containers on zoom.
2. Create a single massive SVG container that holds all shapes and paths, covering the entirety of the window. Position the shapes using SVG shape coordinates. Reposition shapes on zoom, resize SVG container on zoom.

Are there any performance concerns that might favor one method over the other?

Comment: Having one large container might be more performant, but in the end it will depend on your particular use case.

Comment: I don't think there's a difference in performance. One large container will make svg elements manipulation easier. If your elements can overlap, positioning them outside of svg is hard. Consider using <g> element.

Comment: Why do you need to reposition the shapes yourself when you zoom?  Why don't you let the SVG/renderer do that for you?

Comment: Upon zoom, I change the shape X and Y properties to reflect the new size of the div. Is this what you're referring to or is there a better method?